# Clone object which have function stored inside

Tags: javascript

After cloning object with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` function which was stored inside first object is not cloned to second one:

```
obj1: {
   first: true,
   second: function() { return 'test';}
}
var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));
```

After cloning `obj2` has only first property in itself and looks like this:

```
obj2: {
   first: true
}
```

Is there a way to clone function property also?

Comment: JSON has no provisions for function property values. They're ignored. The JSON facility is a fairly limited way to clone objects for that reason.

Comment: const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);

Answer (score 1):

Including a function in an object turns it into a JavaScript object rather than a JSON object, as JSON does not allow the use of functions as property values.

You try this

```
obj2 = { ...obj1 };
```

you can also use a library like lodash to deep clone your object and use it as

```
const _ = required('lodash');

obj2 = _.cloneDeep(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions cannot be encoded into JSON.

You can use the spread syntax for a shallow clone:

```
let obj1 = {a: 10, b: () => "test"};
let obj2 = {...obj1};
// obj2: {a: 10, b: () => "test"}
```

Note that this is a **shallow clone**. So suppose you have some other property `c` in `obj1` that is an object, this code will not clone `c`. Rather it will just point `obj2.c` to the the same object as `obj1.c`.